# On an operator inequality

Tags: operator-theory, power-series, hilbert-spaces, svd, adjoint-operators

Let $A$ and $B$ be two positive, self-adjoint and traceclass operators mapping from some Hilbert space $H$ to it self. Note that we have for any $a, b > 0$, $p>1$

$$(a+b)^p\leq 2^{p-1}(a^p+b^p)$$

I would like to use

$$ \left\| A^p B^{-p} \right\| = \left\| (A-B+B)^pB^{-p} \right\| \leq 2^{p-1} \left( 1 + \left\|(A-B)^pB^{-p} \right\| \right) $$

Is something like this possible? Normally, I would try to argue with an SVD argument but I don't see how to start here.

Comment: Why is $B^{-p}$ a bounded operator?

Comment: Ah sorry i forgot! Normaly I look at $\tilde{A}=(A+\mu I)$ for some smal $\mu>0$ so that $\tilde{A}^{-1}$ is bounded. Does the inequality stil hold if i replace $A,B$ with $\tilde{A}, \tilde{B}$ ??

Comment: I am not sure how to write it in terms of C? Could you explain it a bit further?